# Mysql where clause not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have MySQL Query like this: (I use CodeIgniter)

```
$report = $this->db->query("
          SELECT c.categoryName,
            note1.*,
            ((SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
              FROM notes
              WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'cash_in')
            -
            (SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
             FROM notes
             WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'cash_out')) as trxCount
           FROM notes AS note1
           JOIN
             (SELECT noteDate
              FROM notes
              GROUP BY noteDate
              HAVING COUNT(noteDate) > 0)
            AS note2
              ON note1.noteDate = note2.noteDate
            JOIN category c
              ON c.categoryID = note1.categoryID
            WHERE note1.noteType = 'cash_in'
            ORDER BY note1.noteDate DESC
            LIMIT $start, $per_page
          ")->result();
```

> See on WHERE Clause: WHERE note1.noteType = 'cash_in'

I only want to take the cash data, but why do I get all the data? (including cash out and others). My table also have cash out data

notes table:

> noteID | noteTitle | noteDate | noteAmount | categoryID | noteType

category table

> categoryID | categoryName | parentID

Comment: What error are you getting? Also please post some sample data from the notes and category table as well as an expected output please.

Comment: No error. But the query return all data (cash out and cash in). I only want to get cash in

Comment: Add sample data to your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT noteDate
          FROM notes
          GROUP BY noteDate
          HAVING COUNT(noteDate) > 0
```

is selecting the entire `notes` tables as `note2` (including cash_out entries) and filtering is being done only on entries where `note1.noteType = 'cash_in'`. This will give both `cash_in` and `cash_out` entries as the join condition only checks for `note1.noteDate = note2.noteDate` which will always have some match.

Probably add `where` condition inside the `on` condition and see if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a typo with `cash_in` and `in`.

```
$report = $this->db->query("
          SELECT c.categoryName,
            note1.*,
            ((SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
              FROM notes
              WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'in')
            -
            (SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
             FROM notes
             WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'out')) as trxCount
           FROM notes AS note1
           JOIN
             (SELECT noteDate
              FROM notes
              GROUP BY noteDate
              HAVING COUNT(noteDate) > 0)
            AS note2
              ON note1.noteDate = note2.noteDate
            JOIN category c
              ON c.categoryID = note1.categoryID
            WHERE note1.noteType = 'in'
            ORDER BY note1.noteDate DESC
            LIMIT $start, $per_page
          ")->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a `where` on your `JOIN` statement. If this went on the ON element or within the SELECT itself I believe that would fix your problem.